# .htaccess redirect absolute image path to subfolder

Tags: html, .htaccess, path

I'm developing a website with an other guy that used root absolute path in HTML like

```
<img src="/images/fb-icon.png" border="0">
```

I need to give preview access to website that is now on my NAS in a webfoot subfolder, i can't move it to the root folder, address is like this

```
http://192.168.1.50/mypreview/
```

any way to redirect only broken images path file i guess via .htaccess?

EDIT:

on my NAS i have multiple preview folders like:
http://192.168.1.50/mypreview/ contains preview website, production domain http://mypreview.com/

http://192.168.1.50/mypreview-a/ contains preview website A, production domain http://mypreview-a.com/

http://192.168.1.50/mypreview-b/ contains preview website B, production domain http://mypreview-b.com/

each folder contains a entire website that is corresponding at what i can browse on production web server

i need to add htaccess rules inside /mypreview folder
for each website images are as a subfolder, an example of web site directory three, inside /mypreview/en /mypreview/it i have my php files

```
/mypreview
/mypreview/en
/mypreview/it
/mypreview/images
/mypreview/pdf
/mypreview/common
```

PHP file /mypreview/it/index.php contains

```
<img src="/images/fb-icon.png" border="0">
```

that works correctly on production server since it looks for

http://mypreview.com/images/fb-icon.png

but not on preview environment since it looks for

http://192.168.1.50/images/fb-icon.png

instead of

http://192.168.1.50/mypreview/images/fb-icon.png

Answer (score 0):

To redirect your broken images to root,you can use the following in /subfolder/.htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpg)$">
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/mypreview/
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: i need to put put .htaccess inside mypreview folder since on my nas i have multiple preview websites, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in **root** .htaccess to fix broken paths and rewrite them to `mypreview/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^mypreview/ mypreview%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: i need to put put .htaccess inside mypreview folder since on my nas i have multiple preview websites, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: And out of multiple preview folders which one will `http://images/fb-icon.png` be rewritten to?

Comment: i update my original question, hope i clarify my question, thanks

Comment: If .htaccess is inside `/mypreview` then it cannot handle `/images/fb-icon.png` URI.